# Student Semester Program Table Design in db

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

A student is linked to single program. I have the unique constraint checking single student single program and single semester. but Eventually the student's semester will go up.

Column names are student_id, program_id and semester.

How can i insert data when student goes to higher semester. Do i add semester start and end date then check that all 5 columns have unique constraint.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: It would be defenitely easier if you paste here your model schema.

Comment: @jorzel i have no concrete model schema at the moment . I am seeking suggestions . if you could help me build one, i could get some insight.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique constraint on semesters as well, you cannot insert data when student goes to higher semester. The operation you are looking for is `UPSERT`. So, you either `UPDATE` the existing data or `DELETE` and `INSERT`. But I'd prefer `UPSERT`.

If you need to store the history data of a student passing all the semesters, you better store it in another table. Here, you must not declare a constraint on semester column.

Check this [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you. this is the new operation i heard . UPSERT